# Multithreading in Python vs sequentially

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have a doubt about multithreading in Python using 1 Processor.

1. I understand that if there is a single processor and I execute 3 functions sequentially, the total execution time will be the sum of the 3 functions times

[image]

I tested this using this code and I got the expected results

[image]

2. If I execute the functions using multithreading, it takes around 5 secs
   [image]

But according to what I understand, when we use threads, the processor grants a random time to each thread and resume again until function is finished, it never executes anything in parallel because there is only one processor. I think, in theory it should take as long as it takes sequentially, but the result is different. It takes the time of the most delayed function.

Graphically I think it should work like this, but I don't understand why the threads approach are faster here..

[image]

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. You can't search it, you can't copy it to try it out yourself. It takes up bandwidth unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` doesn't mean the CPU is running the whole time. The thread is free to be put in the background and would resume once the number of seconds has passed. Therefore all the threads can sleep near the start of the program. The program only takes a bit more than 5 seconds to complete because the longest time a thread is sleeping is 5 seconds.